# Struggling to collect and return DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE using User Defined Type

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I'm self taught so please be gentle.

My goal here is to be able to bulk collect headers/values from a dynamic query/cursor in a generated package via

```
    SELECT * 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_val 
    FROM TABLE (CUSTOM.GET_REF_VAL(l_cursor));
```

I have this working successfully for column headers in a similar block of code to GET_REF_VAL (simply RETURN l_col_head before entering the /* COLUMN VALUES */ section).

The errors are coming when I'm trying to assign the return value of DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE into my t_col_val UDT. (Type definitions are in comments)

TYPES

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM.r_col_val IS OBJECT (l_col_val VARCHAR2(250 byte));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM.t_col_val IS TABLE OF CUSTOM.r_col_val;
```

ERRORS

```
--l_val(n) := r_col_val(l_dum_val);    --returns: ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
--l_val(n) := l_dum_val;               --returns: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Table return function GET_REF_VAL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
CUSTOM.GET_REF_VAL
    (
    p_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
RETURN t_col_val
IS

l_val t_col_val := t_col_val();
l_col t_col_head := t_col_head();

n INTEGER := 0;

l_cursor        SYS_REFCURSOR := p_cursor;
l_cursor_id     INTEGER;
l_dummy         INTEGER;
l_col_cnt       INTEGER;
l_tab_rec       DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;
l_dum_val       VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN

    l_cursor_id := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(l_cursor); 
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(l_cursor_id, l_col_cnt, l_tab_rec);

/* COLUMN HEADERS */
FOR r IN 1..l_col_cnt
    LOOP

        l_col.extend;
        n := n + 1;
        l_col(n) := r_col_head(l_tab_rec(r).col_name);
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_id, r, l_dum_val, 4000); 

    END LOOP;

/* COLUMN VALUES */
LOOP 
    IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor_id)> 0 THEN 

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_col_cnt
    LOOP

        l_val.extend;
        n := n + 1;
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor_id, i, l_dum_val);        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_dum_val); -- This return l_dum_val with no issues

        --l_val(n) := r_col_val(l_dum_val); -- ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
        --l_val(n) := l_dum_val; --PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

    END LOOP;

    ELSE 
    EXIT; 
    END IF;
END LOOP;  


DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor_id);
RETURN l_val;

END;
/
```

Execution block

```
DECLARE

l_sql_stmt VARCHAR(10000) :=
q'!
    SELECT
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER') AS OS_USER ,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER') AS SESSION_USER,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','ISDBA') AS ISDBA,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') AS SID,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL') AS CURRENT_SQL,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME') AS DB_NAME,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST') AS HOST,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') AS IP_ADDRESS,
        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') AS SERVICE_NAME
    FROM
        DUAL
!';

l_cursor        SYS_REFCURSOR;
l_cursor_id     INTEGER;
l_dummy         VARCHAR2(50);

TYPE t_cur_head IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(250) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
l_cur_head t_cur_head;

TYPE t_cur_val IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(250) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
l_cur_val t_cur_val;    

BEGIN

l_cursor := CUSTOM.GET_REF_CUR(l_sql_stmt);

IF l_cursor%ISOPEN
THEN

    /* Header fetch works fine */

    /*
    SELECT * 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_head 
    FROM TABLE (CUSTOM.GET_REF_HEAD(l_cursor));

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_head.COUNT
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cur_head(i));
    END LOOP;
    */


    /* Values fetch fails */

    SELECT * 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_val 
    FROM TABLE (CUSTOM.GET_REF_VAL(l_cursor));

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_val.COUNT
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cur_val(i));
    END LOOP;

END IF;

END;
```

So I guess in summary what I want to know is

a) How to handle the return value of dbms_sql.column_value using a user defined type

b) How insert a VARCHAR2 value (l_dum_val) into a UDT object with VARCHAR2 records (l_col_val)

c) Any other obvious errors/bad practices in the code?

Thank you for your time an patience.

Answer (score 2):

The first of your commented-out lines:

```
    --l_val(n) := r_col_val(l_dum_val); -- ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
```

gets that error because you are not resetting `n` to zero before the second loop. You don't really need that counter variable at all though, you can do use `l_val.count` instead (in both loops).

The second of your commented-out lines:

```
    --l_val(n) := l_dum_val; --PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

gets that error because the `l_val(n)` is pointing to an object, which has a string attribute; it isn't pointing directly to a string. So you can assign a new object via its constructor; which is what the first version was trying to do, but it should be:

```
    l_val(l_val.count) := r_col_val(l_dum_val);
```

Once that object exists you can assign the attribute directly with:

```
    l_val(some_index).l_col_val := r_col_val(l_dum_val);
```

but you have to create an object before you can access its attributes, and as you only have a default constructor, that probably isn't going to be much use to you in this case.

So with those changes (and some indentation, and refactoring slightly to get rid of the `else`) this now works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
GET_REF_VAL
    (
    p_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
RETURN t_col_val
IS

    l_val t_col_val := t_col_val();
    l_col t_col_head := t_col_head();

    l_cursor        SYS_REFCURSOR := p_cursor;
    l_cursor_id     INTEGER;
    l_dummy         INTEGER;
    l_col_cnt       INTEGER;
    l_tab_rec       DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;
    l_dum_val       VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN

    l_cursor_id := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(l_cursor); 
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(l_cursor_id, l_col_cnt, l_tab_rec);

    /* COLUMN HEADERS */
    FOR r IN 1..l_col_cnt
    LOOP

        l_col.extend;
        l_col(l_col.count) := r_col_head(l_tab_rec(r).col_name);
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_id, r, l_dum_val, 4000); 

    END LOOP;

    /* COLUMN VALUES */
    LOOP 
        IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor_id) = 0 THEN 
            EXIT; 
        END IF;

        FOR i IN 1 .. l_col_cnt
        LOOP

            l_val.extend;
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor_id, i, l_dum_val);        
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_dum_val);
            l_val(l_val.count) := r_col_val(l_dum_val);

        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;  

    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor_id);
    RETURN l_val;

END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5f87c26f83aee36742c863587bfe303)

---

Your code suggests you have a separate function to get the headers, so you're duplicating code. You could simplify into one procedure with two out variables instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
GET_REF_HEAD_AND_VAL
    (
    p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_col OUT SYS.odcivarchar2list,
    p_val OUT SYS.odcivarchar2list
    )
IS

    l_cursor_id     INTEGER;
    l_col_cnt       INTEGER;
    l_tab_rec       DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB3;
    l_value         VARCHAR2(250 byte);

BEGIN

    l_cursor_id := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(p_cursor); 
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS3(l_cursor_id, l_col_cnt, l_tab_rec);

    /* COLUMN HEADERS */
    p_col := SYS.odcivarchar2list();
    FOR r IN 1..l_col_cnt
    LOOP

        p_col.extend;
        p_col(p_col.count) := l_tab_rec(r).col_name;
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor_id, r, l_value, 250);

    END LOOP;

    /* COLUMN VALUES */
    p_val := SYS.odcivarchar2list();
    LOOP 
        IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor_id) = 0 THEN 
            EXIT; 
        END IF;

        FOR i IN 1 .. l_col_cnt
        LOOP

            p_val.extend;
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor_id, i, l_value);        
            --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_dum_val);
            p_val(p_val.count) := l_value;

        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;  

    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor_id);

END;
/
```

This is using a built-in collection type rather than creating your own object/table types (though you could still create your own collection type; it doesn't need to used objects though).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b41eb61124849497ccacaa9d873cfbf)

Comment: You are an absolute hero! Thank you.

I did originally plan on a separate function for column/values so I could call each based on what was required but since I need to define columns to get values I guess it does make sense to pass them from one procedure.


I've never seen an odcivarchar2list either so thanks for that too!


BTW very impressive profile! I hope to attain such knowledge myself some day.



One of my favourite quotes
“A jack of all trades is a master of none, but often times better than a master of one.”


Peace